# Problems  writing to a file

Tags: java, android, file-io, ioexception, fileoutputstream

I am trying to write to a file in an Android app with this code:

```
File save = new File("sdcard/save.txt"); 
if(!save.exists()) {
    try {
        save.createNewFile();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

try {
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(save);
    OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fos);

    osw.write("1");
    osw.flush();
    osw.close();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

However, my debugger goes to the `IOException` after the line `osw.close();`

The problem is by that stage `e` doesn't exist, so I cant read the exception message.

I added the right premission in the androidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: Try with this, "/sdcard/save.txt", as per Samir Mangroliya, this way is not good.

Comment: errr - no  - you need to use android to get the root of the relevant directory structure using Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()

Comment: Can you please add your logcat?

Comment: here is the logcat file

http://www.file-upload.net/download-4668321/log.txt.html

thats only the log from the debugging of the  30lines.

so the file exist...the line save.createNewFile(); works...i have the file in my directory

Comment: and the app isnt printing the stacktrace in the console...so i dont know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 File save = new File("sdcard/save.txt"); is bad code
```

**use below code**

```
String path= Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
String fileName = "myFile.txt";

File file = new File(path + File.separator + fileName);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to give the permission in `manifest.xml`.

Comment: i did it
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

Comment: It is working fine at my end.I am not getting any exception.and close the outputstreamwriter in finally block.

Answer (score 0):

I have recently written a file to my sdcard this way:

```
private static final String sdcardPath = "/mnt/sdcard/yourfolder_or_fileName"
File folder = new File(path);
```

But you should use, as mentioned above, this solution

```
String path= Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
```